# Ionic 3 password and confirm password validation using formBuilder

Tags: angular, validation, ionic-framework, ionic3, formbuilder

I have a **change password** and it has a `formBuilde` that will validate each field in the **form**. I want to validate the `confirmPassword` and the `newPassword` in realtime.

This is what I have done so far:

in my **provider.ts** that I had imported in my **page.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable()
export class ValidationServiceProvider {

    constructor() {
        console.log('Hello ErrorHandlerProvider Provider')
    }

    // Validation for password and confirm password
    static MatchPassword(AC: AbstractControl) {
       const newPassword = AC.get('newPassword').value // to get value in input tag
       const confirmPassword = AC.get('confirmPassword').value // to get value in input tag
        if(newPassword != confirmPassword) {
            console.log('false');
            AC.get('confirmPassword').setErrors( { MatchPassword: true } )
        } else {
            console.log('true')
            AC.get('confirmPassword').setErrors(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I had an static `method` that will be calld in my **page.ts**

Now in my ts file.

Import the **provider**

```
import { ValidationServiceProvider } from '../../providers/validation-service';
```

and now the `formBuilder`

```
this.changePasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      oldPassword: [
        "",
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.minLength(4),
          Validators.required
        ])
      ],
      newPassword: [
        "",
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.minLength(4),
          Validators.required
        ])
      ],
      confirmPassword: [
        "",
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.minLength(4),
          Validators.required
        ])
      ],
    }, {
      validator: ValidationServiceProvider.MatchPassword // Inject the provider method
    });
```

Now in my **html file**

```
<form [formGroup]="changePasswordForm" (submit)="submit()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>
          Your Old Password
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="oldPassword" type="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>
          Your New Password
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="newPassword" type="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>
          Confirm Password
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" type="password"></ion-input>
        <p *ngIf="changePasswordForm.controls['confirmPassword'].errors?.MatchPassword" style="color: red">New password and Confirm password did not match</p>
      </ion-item>
        <button *ngIf="!changingPassword" type="submit" [disabled]="!changePasswordForm.valid" color="primary" ion-button block>Submit</button>

        <button *ngIf="changingPassword" color="primary" disabled ion-button block>
          <div class="center-vertical-horizontal">
            Processing...
            <ion-spinner class="button-spinner" name="crescent"></ion-spinner>
          </div>
        </button>
    </form>
```

Everything is working fine, But I want to display the text message to the user if the **newPassword** and the **confirmPassword** did not match.

Code below but not working.

```
<p *ngIf="changePasswordForm.controls['confirmPassword'].errors?.MatchPassword" style="color: red">New password and Confirm password did not match</p>
```

There are no errors at all. The p tag just won't display which I would want to.

I just followed this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/@ibrahimalsurkhi/match-password-validation-with-angular-2) but didn't have enough much luck.

Can someone shed some light for me?

Thanks in advance.
Appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara none. I edited the question sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code. But I've changed the `<p>` ta to a `<ion-label>` now it is working fine.

```
  <ion-label *ngIf="changePasswordForm.get('confirmPassword').errors?.MatchPassword" style="color: red">
                New password and Confirm password did not match
  </ion-label>
```

Find the  working example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-a4jsxz)

Comment: Identifier MatchPassword is not defined

Comment: It is working. But typescript or html gives me a strict typing of error in this line. `*ngIf="changePasswordForm.get('confirmPassword').errors?.MatchPassword"` it says that **[Angular] Identifier 'MatchPassword' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member** in my main app. But in stackblitz it is working perfectly fine. I just want to remove the error in the html even if it works

Comment: change `changePasswordForm.get('confirmPassword')` to

`changePasswordForm.controls['confirmPassword']` in the html